# Spring-Boot App with CompletableFuture , How to manage large number of request?

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, completable-future

I understand a **Spring-Boot** app has *server.tomcat.max-threads = 200* by default,
Lets say now I have a Rest controller , in service I am using a **CompletableFuture** for calling another third party API asynchronously.
Now Assume I get 100 requests at same time for my API, (Which invokes 100 more threads for 3rd party API).

Now the question is will the CompletableFuture threads also be considered from the server.tomcat.max-threads or they are from different thread quota ForkJoinPool.commonPool().

What if I get 101th request , will that be a blocker until others complete.

Just wanted to understand how my application will behave in huge amount of request.
Can I control this ? Any advice will help me to design my application and avoid any flaw in advance.

Comment: When you create a new thread pool (`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);`) it's not related to tomcat's thread pool. When a request come to server, tomcat will use one of 200 threads to process, if there is 201 requests come to server then the last (201th) request have to wait the first 200 requests done. So if you want to serve a huge amount of request, you will need improve the ability to handle requests, especially the database